# Camel routes are not getting identified, when running the application, getting 0 of 0 total routes started

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a camel application and it does not recognize the routes.  It is a spring boot
application.

This is the spring boot application class

I have defined all the properties in the yaml file.
But when the applciation starts up it says 0 of o routes.  Any idea why it can be showing it.

And my pom.xml has the following entries.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.dsfsdaf.orchestration</groupId>
    <artifactId>orchen-con-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
    <name>OrchServi</name>
    <description>Orch</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <camel.version>3.1.0</camel.version>
        <jackson.version>1.9.13</jackson.version>
        <kafka.version>2.6.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-kafka-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${kafka.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>2.10.0</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- This dependency is for WebClient implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolt-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.jolt</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The camel context file is as below:  This is the camel routing file

```xml
<beans xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
            http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel- 
            spring.xsd"
            xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">

    <bean id="routeIRIntake" class="com.adsfdsaf.orch.camel.transformer.TransClass"/>
    <!-- Camel routes for orch module -->
    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camel">
        <route id="orch">

            <from id="cdi-log" uri="{{kafka-uri-base}}{{kafkaProp}}" />
            <process ref="routeIRIntake" />
            <log id="cdi-payload-clq" message="somemsg" />
            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.camel.header.http.name}}">
                <constant>{{orch.http.method.post}}</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.http.header.content-type}}">
                <simple>{{orch.http.header.app-json}}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.http.header.accept}}">
                <simple>{{orch.http.header.app-json}}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <log id="pld-to-sch" message="Routing to schval" />
            <to uri="{{orch.sch-val.uri}}" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == ${status.success} </simple>

                    <log id="schema-val-success" message="message for success" />
                    <to uri="{{kafka-inb-intake}}{{kafkaProp}}" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log id="schema-validation-failed" message="failed message " />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>
        <route id="intnotif">
            <from id="intnotif-log" uri="{{kafka-outbound}}{{kafkaProp}}" />
            <log id="log-notif" message="Received resp" />
            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.camel.header.http.name}}">
                <constant>{{orch.http.method.post}}</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.http.header.content-type}}">
                <simple>{{orch.http.header.app-json}}</simple>
            </setHeader>

            <setHeader headerName="{{orch.http.header.accept}}">
                <simple>{{orch.http.header.app-json}}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="{{notif.serv.uri}}" />
            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${header.CamelHttpResponseCode} == ${status.success} </simple>
                    <log id="notification-success" message="success message" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <log id="notification-failed" message="failed message" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: I have 2 routes defined as per the camel-context.xml file but it still says Total 0 of 0 routes started.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that you miss the `@ImportResource` SB annotation on the main application class. Assuming you have a `camel-context.xml` file under `src/main/resources`, it should be something like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({"classpath:camel-context.xml"})
public class Application {
//...
```

There is a full example [here](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot-examples/tree/camel-spring-boot-examples-3.7.0/camel-example-spring-boot-xml).